# parallel --max-procs 4 echo ::: {1..4} produces no output?

Tags: gnu-parallel

When I run the following command:

```
 parallel --max-procs 4 echo ::: {1..4}
```

in my PC, it produces the expected output, 1, 2, 3, 4 (in different lines). However, when I run the same command on another computer (which has `parallel` installed), it doesn't produce output. Both PCs have Ubuntu 14.04 installed (the one where the command works has Ubuntu desktop and the other has Ubuntu server). I know this is a broad question, but what could be the problem??

Running `echo {1..4}` produces output in both computers.

**Additional info:** Running `help` on the console on both computers (the one where `parallel` works and the one where it doesn't produce output) gives:

`GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

on both computers. Running `parallel --version` gives:

```
GNU parallel 20130922
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:

O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool, 
;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.
```

on *both* computers.

It should be noted that I am accessing *both* computers remotely through `ssh`, from a *third* computer, but I don't think that's important (or is it?). Any additional information you need just ask.

Comment: Are you sure that `parallel` executed the command in a shell that supports the `{1..4}` syntax? - If not then try to execute an appropriate shell instead, as in `bash -c 'echo ::: {1..4}'`, as command given to `parallel`. (OTOH, the brace expression should anyway be expanded by the local shell.)

Comment: What is the output of '--version'?

Comment: If the output contains: "WARNING: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu." then it actually is an answer.

Comment: @OleTange Wouldn't GNU parallel with `--tollef` print out `parallel: Input is read from the terminal. Only experts do this on purpose. Press CTRL-D to exit.` with these parameters? And the actual Tollef (moreutils) `parallel` complains about `-` being an invalid option.

Comment: @Giles GNU Parallel (version 20130222-20140122) will warn about --tollef, but will not read from stdin (as it is in --tollef mode, which does not read from stdin). Tollef's parallel (part of moreutils) will complain: "parallel: invalid option -- '-'"

Comment: `parallel --version` outputs: 

GNU parallel 20130922
Copyright (C) 2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013 Ole Tange and Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using GNU Parallel for a publication please cite:

O. Tange (2011): GNU Parallel - The Command-Line Power Tool, 
;login: The USENIX Magazine, February 2011:42-47.

Comment: @Janis It supports `{1..4}`, because running `echo {1..4}` produces the expected output.

Comment: @becko, yes, see my comment after "OTOH"; as you used it that should anyway be already expanded by the **local** shell (presuming local shell supports it), so it would be in any case passed to `parallel` in the expanded form `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: Try: parallel -D echo ::: 1 2 3 4, and parallel --plain echo ::: 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I had zero free disk space on the PC that was giving trouble! Maybe this is too specific, but I am going to leave this here anyway, in case someone else runs into a similar problem.

Comment: Newer versions of GNU Parallel check if the disk is full. Can you test if 20150222 also gives no output?

Comment: @OleTange I already freed the disk space on the PC, so I cannot do the test now.